# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'html.entities'; 'html' is not a package

Tags: python, django, python-3.8, setup.py

Newbie coder here. So im trying to pipenv install django but i keep getting this error :

```
$ pipenv install django
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: C:\Users\wesleyromero308\Desktop\Pipfile
Using C:/Users/wesleyromero308/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe (3.8.0) to create virtualenv...
[=   ] Creating virtual environment...ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'html.entities'; 'html' is not a package

Failed creating virtual environment
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]: 2022-08-06 01:08:46.004 ERROR   root: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'html.entities'; 'html' is not a package

Failed to create virtual environment.
```

I then went and did pip install htmlentities and it was successful. Then i did pip install html and got this error:

```
$ pip install html
Collecting html
  Using cached html-1.16.tar.gz (7.6 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  python setup.py egg_ifo did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1

  [1 lines of output]
  ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment.
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Encountered error while generating package metadata.

See above for output.
```

Please help, i just want to install django lol i been stuck for days now

Answer (score 0):

##### About your error

> Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment.

`html` package needs `setuptools` pkg first

##### Create VirtualEnv using:

```bash
cd project
python3.8 -m venv <name-of-your-env>
# activate the virtual env just created
source bin/<name-of-your-env>/activate
```

##### Now installing Django should be fine:

```bash
pip install Django
```

##### If you want to deactivate the virtual env

```bash
cd project
deactivate
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick response. However, when i did that i got this . $ python3.8 -m venv <store-front-env>
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Comment: you've to run like: `python3.8 -m venv store-front-env`, No angle brackets.